# Error after update Angular 4 project to Angular 7

Tags: angular

I get the following 'ngOutletContext' error while build production mode.

How to resolve this error ?

```
ERROR in : Can't bind to 'ngOutletContext' since it isn't a known property of 'ng-template'.
1. If 'ngOutletContext' is an Angular directive, then add 
'CommonModule' to the '@NgModule.imports' of this component.
2. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the 
'@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("
    <div class="value"
        *ngIf="optionList.hasSelected">
        <ng-template [ERROR ->][ngOutletContext]="{option: 
optionList.selection[0], onDeselectOptionClick: 
onDeselectOptionClick}" [")
: Property binding ngOutletContext not used by any directive on an 
 embedded template. Make sure that the property name is spelled 
 correctly and all directives are listed in the 
 "@NgModule.declarations". ("
    <div class="value"
        *ngIf="optionList.hasSelected">
        [ERROR ->]<ng-template [ngOutletContext]="{option: 
    optionList.selection[0], onDeselectOptionClick: onDeselectOp")
```

Answer (score 0):

ngOutletContext has been removed as it was deprecated since v4. Use ngTemplateOutletContext instead of ngOutletContext.

Comment: where to find 'ngOutletContext' in node_modules ? because i did not use it manually in any file.

Comment: you will not get ngOutletContext in mode module now if you are using angular v5 are higher. you will get ngTemplateOutletContext .